# Save Tag Images from MS Tag Rest

Tags: php, microsoft-tag

I'm trying to create some Microsoft Tags using the MS Tag Rest Interface (http://tag.ws.suddenelfilio.net/). I have an API key and was able to create the tag, unfortunately I don't really know how to save it as an image.
I have saved the result of the "Generating the barcode" request as an image, and it's about 280k big. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be a valid jped file, imagecreatefromstring() didn't work either. imagecreatefromstring returns a

```
"Warning: imagecreatefromstring() [function.imagecreatefromstring]: Data is not in a recognized format".
```

Here's a short snippet of the string I get returned:

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL/2wBDAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjL/wAARCAdyCA8DASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQID
```

Anyone got this working? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with the help of Musa I  finally figured out how to do this, here's the working code

Thanks, this was a key part to solving this. Here's my now working code:

```
$url = 'http://tag.ws.suddenelfilio.net/mstagrest.svc/GenerateQRcode?at={access-token}&cn=Main&tn=Test&it=jpeg&s=1&ht=true';

// Get page content with curl   
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$pagecontent = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);

// Decode it    
$pagecontent = base64_decode($pagecontent);
// Create Image
$im = imagecreatefromstring($pagecontent);
// Save as jpeg
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($im, 'image.jpeg');       

imagedestroy($im);
```

Answer (score 2):

That's looks base64 encoded decode it( with `base64_decode`) before you pass it to `imagecreatefromstring`, or just save it after you decode.

Comment: Thanks, this was a key part to solving this. I added my working code below.